# Puppeteer - Protocol error (Page.navigate): Target closed

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless, node-cluster

As you can see with the sample code below, I'm using Puppeteer with a cluster of workers in Node to run multiple requests of websites screenshots by a given URL:

```js
const cluster = require('cluster');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function getScreenshot(domain) {
    let screenshot;
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--disable-dev-shm-usage'] });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    try {
        await page.goto('http://' + domain + '/', { timeout: 60000, waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    } catch (error) {
        try {
            await page.goto('http://' + domain + '/', { timeout: 120000, waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
            screenshot = await page.screenshot({ type: 'png', encoding: 'base64' });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Connecting to: ' + domain + ' failed due to: ' + error);
        }

    await page.close();
    await browser.close();

    return screenshot;
}

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    const numOfWorkers = require('os').cpus().length;
    for (let worker = 0; worker < numOfWorkers; worker++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }

    cluster.on('exit', function (worker, code, signal) {
        console.debug('Worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died with code: ' + code + ', and signal: ' + signal);
        Cluster.fork();
    });

    cluster.on('message', function (handler, msg) {
        console.debug('Worker: ' + handler.process.pid + ' has finished working on ' + msg.domain + '. Exiting...');
        if (Cluster.workers[handler.id]) {
            Cluster.workers[handler.id].kill('SIGTERM');
        }
    });
} else {
    const app = express();
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.listen(80, function() {
        console.debug('Worker ' + process.pid + ' is listening to incoming messages');
    });

    app.post('/screenshot', (req, res) => {
        const domain = req.body.domain;

        getScreenshot(domain)
            .then((screenshot) =>
                try {
                    process.send({ domain: domain });
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Error while exiting worker ' + process.pid + ' due to: ' + error);
                }

                res.status(200).json({ screenshot: screenshot });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                try {
                    process.send({ domain: domain });
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Error while exiting worker ' + process.pid + ' due to: ' + error);
                }

                res.status(500).json({ error: error });
            });
    });
}
```

Some explanation:

1. Each time a request arrives a worker will process it and kill itself at the end
2. Each worker creates a new browser instance with a single page, and if a page took more than 60sec to load, it will retry reloading it (in the same page because maybe some resources has already been loaded) with timeout of 120sec
3. Once finished both the page and the browser will be closed

My problem is that some legitimate domains get errors that I can't explain:

```
Error: Protocol error (Page.navigate): Target closed.
```

```
Error: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Session closed. Most likely the page has been closed.
```

I read at some git issue (that I can't find now) that it can happen when the page redirects and adds 'www' at the start, but I'm hoping it's false...
Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: any findings...?

Comment: @Sajuuk Unfortunately not really... but I watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARt3zDHSsd4) video and thought to lose the cluster and try a PubSub architecture where the Puppeteer server will read the hostnames, return screenshot and move to the next one

Comment: If you recently upgraded to macOS Catalina, see this issue: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/5020

Answer (score 79, accepted):

### What "Target closed" means

When you launch a browser via `puppeteer.launch` it will start a browser and connect to it. From there on any function you execute on your opened browser (like `page.goto`) will be send via the [Chrome DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) to the browser. A target means a tab in this context.

The *Target closed* exception is thrown when you are trying to run a function, but the target (tab) was already closed.

### Similar error messages

The error message was recently changed to give more meaningful information. It now gives the following message:

> Error: Protocol error (Target.activateTarget): Session closed. Most likely the page has been closed.

---

### Why does it happen

There are multiple reasons why this could happen.

- **You used a resource that was already closed**

  Most likely, you are seeing this message because you closed the tab/browser and are still trying to use the resource. To give an simple example:

  ```js
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await browser.close();
  await page.goto('http://www.google.com');
  ```

  In this case the browser was closed and after that, a `page.goto` was called resulting in the error message. Most of the time, it will not be that obvious. Maybe an error handler already closed the page during a cleanup task, while your script is still crawling.
- **The browser crashed or was unable to initialize**

  I also experience this every few hundred requests. There is an [issue about this](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1947) on the puppeteer repository as well. It seems to be the case, when you are using a lot of memory or CPU power. Maybe you are spawning a lot of browser? In these cases the browser might crash or disconnect.

  I found no "silver bullet" solution to this problem. But you might want to check out the library [puppeteer-cluster](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster) (disclaimer: I'm the author) which handles these kind of error cases and let's you retry the URL when the error happens. It can also manage a pool of browser instances and would also simplify your code.

Comment: I'm getting this for nearly 95%of the requests.

Comment: would this happen if the resource somehow never never opened a page, like in the case of some failure to initialise?

Comment: @JamesCat Yes, that's possible when the browser crashes during initialization for example.

Comment: @ThomasDondorf just a quick note for others, I resolved this, the problem was I was running playwright in a docker container build from node:Erbium and I did not have all the required dependencies

Comment: I would have posted a new a nswer but this is correct, just remember to add `await` in front of  `browser.close()`

Comment: I get this with 100% of requests for certain web pages

Comment: You can also get this by accidentally omitting `await` from other commands, e.g. `page.keyboard.press('Enter')`

Comment: `puppeteer-cluster` by @ThomasDondorf here works wonderfully for me to avoid the above problem. ✨ https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster

Comment: Thanks @RaineRevere, that fixed it for me !

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant explanation! This helped me to find out where the bug was.

Answer (score 19):

For me removing `'--single-process'` from `args` fixed the issue.

```
puppeteerOptions: {
    headless: true,
    args: [
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        '--no-first-run',
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--no-zygote',
        '--deterministic-fetch',
        '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins',
        '--disable-site-isolation-trials',
        // '--single-process',
    ],
}
```

Comment: June 30, 2021 -- this was the correct answer for me.

Comment: '--disable-site-isolation-trials' worked for me

Comment: In my case `--no-sandbox` solved it

Answer (score 12):

I've wound up at this thread a few times, and the typical culprit is that I forgot to `await` a Puppeteer `page` call that returned a promise, causing a race condition.

Here's a minimal example of what this can look like:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  page.goto("https://www.stackoverflow.com"); // whoops, forgot await!
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close())
;
```

Output is:

```
C:\Users\foo\Desktop\puppeteer-playground\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Connection.js:217
            this._callbacks.set(id, { resolve, reject, error: new Error(), method });
                                                              ^

Error: Protocol error (Page.navigate): Target closed.
    at C:\Users\foo\Desktop\puppeteer-playground\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Connection.js:217:63
```

In this case, it seems like an unmissable error, but in a larger chunk of code and the promise is nested or in a condition, it's easy to overlook.

You'll get a similar error for forgetting to `await` a `page.click()` or other promise call, for example, `Error: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Target closed.`, which can be seen in the question [UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Target closed. (Puppeteer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50645321/unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-error-protocol-error-runtime-callfunctionon)

<sub>*This is a contribution to the thread as a canonical resource for the error and may not be the solution to OP's problem, although the fundamental race condition seems to be a likely cause.*</sub>

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'close') !!!

Comment: You can use `browser?.close()` if the `launch` is throwing.

Comment: Just call "finally()" and browse is 'undefined'

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `finally` is a cleanup handler, not something you call. The only way for `browser` to be undefined inside `finally` is if `launch()` throws, but I've edited the post to handle that with optional chaining.

Answer (score 10):

I was just experiencing the same issue every time I tried running my puppeteer script*. The [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51989560/1790950) did not resolve this issue for me.

I got it to work by removing and reinstalling the puppeteer package:

```
npm remove puppeteer
npm i puppeteer
```

*I only experienced this issue when setting the headless option to 'false`

Comment: same here, but this did not work unfortunately. @Timo which puppeteer version were you using?

Answer (score 6):

In 2021 I'm receiving the very similar following error `Error: Error pdf creationError: Protocol error (Target.setDiscoverTargets): Target closed.`, I solved it by playing with different args, so if your production server has a `pipe:true` flag in `puppeteer.launch` obj it will produce errors.

Also `--disable-dev-shm-usage` flag do the trick

The solution below works for me:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: true,
  // pipe: true, <-- delete this property
  args: [
    '--no-sandbox',
    '--disable-dev-shm-usage', // <-- add this one
    ],
});
```

Comment: And what do these flags mean?

Comment: [Here](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) you can find a description

Comment: This is funny, I just replaced my launch() call with this, executed everything as always and it fixed it! However I then completely reverted to my origina, simple `const browser = await puppeteer.launch();` call and now it's still working.

Answer (score 3):

After hours of frustrations I realized that this happens when it goes to a new page and I need to be using `await page.waitForNavigation()` before I do anything and after I press a button or do any action that will cause it to redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Check your jest-puppeteer.config.js file.
I made the below mistake

```
module.exports = {
    launch: {
        headless: false,
        browserContext: "default",
    },
};
```

and after correcting it as below

```
module.exports = {
    launch: {
        headless: false
    },
    browserContext: "default",
};
```

everything worked just fine!!!

Answer (score 0):

The solution below works for me:

```
puppeteer: {
  headless: true,
  args: [
    "--no-sandbox",
    "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
    "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
    "--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas",
    "--no-first-run",
    "--no-zygote",
    // "--single-process",
    "--disable-gpu",
  ],
},
```