# Pyppeteer behaving differently on Linux and Windows

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome-devtools, python-asyncio, puppeteer, pyppeteer

I have `pyppeteer` code that browses around. Let's assume it only clicks on `a` tags.

It runs fine on my local Windows machine, but breaks whenever I run it remotely on a Linux server. Same `conda env`, same code.

The relevant part of my code, simplified, looks like:

```py
async def act(self):
    element = self.element

    async def get_action():
        tag_name = await self.page.evaluate(
            'elem => { return elem.tagName.toLowerCase(); }',
            element)
        action = None
        if tag_name == 'a':
            action = element.click()
        else:
            action = async_pass()
        return action

    async def get_action_future():
        # gather syntax based on:
        # https://miyakogi.github.io/pyppeteer/reference.html#pyppeteer.page.Page.click
        action = await get_action()
        future_action = asyncio.gather(
            action,
            asyncio.sleep(0.001),  # dirty, dirty work-around, doesn't work nicely otherwise
        )
        waited_future = await asyncio.shield(future_action)
        if waited_future[0] is None:
            await self.page.waitForNavigation(self.wait_options)
        return None

    await get_action_future()
```

It runs fine on my Windows machine.
When I start it on a Linux machine, it starts off OK, whether there's navigation or not. Then, after a few navigation clicks, I'm getting a timeout, then another error:

```
Error encountered: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 20000 ms exceeded.
# then I trigger the element selector and the act method again, wrapped in try/except
Error encountered: Protocol Error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Session closed. Most likely the page has been closed.
```

I'm stuck on this problem for a while and would appreciate any help!

My environment includes:
`python=3.6, pyppeteer=0.0.25`.

*BTW:
I noticed that [this question has a similar error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51629151). BUT, the error is different (`Protocol error (Page.navigate): Target closed` instead of `Protocol Error (Runtime.callFunctionOn)`), as well as the environment (`node.js`, `Puppeteer`, etc.).*

Comment: Did you try to set higher timeout? See example [here](https://github.com/miyakogi/pyppeteer/issues/66).

Comment: Hi @MikhailGerasimov, yes I have. I am passing a `timeout` argument. Even at ridiculously long timeouts (100 secs), it still crashes.

`pyppeteer.errors.NetworkError: Protocol error Runtime.callFunctionOn: Target closed.` or `Error encountered: Protocol Error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Session closed. Most likely the page has been closed.`

Comment: @YardenR - Did you manage to find a solution for this? I'm experiencing the exact same issue and am wondering if it's to do with packages missing on the server

Comment: @Calum I did not.
From what I recall, I think it was linked to a Chromium bug? I'm not sure, it was a while ago :D I'm not actively working on this project anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I switched to Selenium and it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [Pypepeteer](https://github.com/miyakogi/pyppeteer) is no longer maintained. I was experiencing the same issue and migrated to [Selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/trunk/py) which is working well.