# "Fixing Puppeteer Node.js Error: TargetCloseError - Protocol error (Network.enable) - Target closed

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I've created a web scraper using Puppeteer in Node.js. However, when I run the program, I encounter the following error: TargetCloseError:Protocolerror(Network.enable):Targetclosed. I've noticed that this error tends to occur when I rapidly open and close a large number of tabs, which may be overloading the browser.

Here is my code:

```
import vanillaPuppeteer from 'puppeteer'
import {addExtra} from "puppeteer-extra";
import StealthPlugin from 'puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth'
import AdblockerPlugin from "puppeteer-extra-plugin-adblocker";
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import axios from "axios";
import * as cheerio from 'cheerio';
import {Cluster} from "puppeteer-cluster";

...

const fetchData = async (query) => {
    try {
        return await axios.post('https://eintaxid.com/search-ajax.php', `&query=${query}`)
    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }
}

(async () => {
    dotenv.config()

    const puppeteer = addExtra(vanillaPuppeteer)
    puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin())
    puppeteer.use(AdblockerPlugin())

    const queries = process.env.QUERIES.split(',')
    for (const query of queries) {
        const {data: content} = await fetchData(query)
        const $ = cheerio.load(content)

        const links = []
        $('a').each((i, a) => {
            const href = $(a).attr('href')
            links.push(`https://eintaxid.com${href}`)
        })

        const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
            puppeteer,
            concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_CONTEXT,
            maxConcurrency: 2,
            puppeteerOptions: {
                defaultViewport: false,
                headless: false,
                args: ['--no-sandbox']
            }
        })

        await cluster.task(async ({page, data: link}) => {
            await page.goto(link, {
                waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
            })
            const data = await parseData(await page.content())
            console.log(data)
        })

        for (const link of links) {
            cluster.queue(link)
        }

        await cluster.idle()
        await cluster.close()
    }
})()
```

Here is my package.json dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.5.0",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.12",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "puppeteer": "^21.2.1",
    "puppeteer-cluster": "^0.23.0",
    "puppeteer-extra": "^3.3.6",
    "puppeteer-extra-plugin-adblocker": "^2.13.6",
    "puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth": "^2.11.2",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1"
  }
```

Here is my .env file

```
QUERIES=Repair,Rent
```

Here is an error:

```
file:///D:/Work/Orders/RG/eintaxid.com-scraper/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:142
            this._reject(callback, new TargetCloseError('Target closed'));
                                   ^

TargetCloseError: Protocol error (Network.enable): Target closed
    at CallbackRegistry.clear (file:///D:/Work/Orders/RG/eintaxid.com-scraper/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:142:36)
    at CDPSessionImpl._onClosed (file:///D:/Work/Orders/RG/eintaxid.com-scraper/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:493:25)       
    at Connection.onMessage (file:///D:/Work/Orders/RG/eintaxid.com-scraper/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:251:25)
    at WebSocket.<anonymous> (file:///D:/Work/Orders/RG/eintaxid.com-scraper/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/NodeWebSocketTransport.js:46:32)
    at callListener (D:\Work\Orders\RG\eintaxid.com-scraper\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:290:14)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (D:\Work\Orders\RG\eintaxid.com-scraper\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:209:9)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (D:\Work\Orders\RG\eintaxid.com-scraper\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:1192:20)
    at Receiver.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at Receiver.dataMessage (D:\Work\Orders\RG\eintaxid.com-scraper\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:558:14) {
  cause: ProtocolError
      at <instance_members_initializer> (file:///D:/Work/Orders/RG/eintaxid.com-scraper/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:46:14)
      at new Callback (file:///D:/Work/Orders/RG/eintaxid.com-scraper/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:50:16)
      at CallbackRegistry.create (file:///D:/Work/Orders/RG/eintaxid.com-scraper/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:89:26)       
      at Connection._rawSend (file:///D:/Work/Orders/RG/eintaxid.com-scraper/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:210:26)
      at CDPSessionImpl.send (file:///D:/Work/Orders/RG/eintaxid.com-scraper/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:458:33)
      at NetworkManager.addClient (file:///D:/Work/Orders/RG/eintaxid.com-scraper/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/NetworkManager.js:92:20)  
      at FrameManager.initialize (file:///D:/Work/Orders/RG/eintaxid.com-scraper/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/FrameManager.js:181:54)    
      at FrameManager.onAttachedToTarget (file:///D:/Work/Orders/RG/eintaxid.com-scraper/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/FrameManager.js:235:19)
      at #onAttachedToTarget (file:///D:/Work/Orders/RG/eintaxid.com-scraper/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/Page.js:262:28)
      at file:///D:/Work/Orders/RG/eintaxid.com-scraper/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/third_party/mitt/index.js:1:243
}

Node.js v18.17.1
```

I've attempted to find a solution for this error, but I haven't come across any fixes. Has anyone else encountered this issue and could share a solution?

Comment: Could you provide the function fetchData?

Comment: You are opening several browser instances for each query,  place a breakpoint in await fetchData(query) and other in await cluster.close() and debug your code. You will see that just for the first query loads ore browser instances are open. Maybe this is what you want to do, but since I am using different urls in .env than you I got other kind of errors. Could you provide also the urls that you are using?

Comment: I changed the method axios.post to axios.get and the code runs ok without errors, I get no results because I don't have your .env and because https://website/search-ajax.php doesn't exists

Comment: @ManuelMB sorry I have provided wrong fetchData method (url was not valid), I changed it and I also added .env file so you can try again.

Comment: I will try it but later, I have things to do know

Comment: I tried your code and it works perfect without any errors, I am using node v18.16.1 but I will install the same version than you to also try it and will tell you the result.

Comment: It also works perfect with the same version of Node,js that you are using Node.js v18.17.1. I am using this simple parseData function. 



const parseData = async (data) => {
    try {
        console.log(data)
    } catch (error) {  
        throw error
    }
}

Comment: Here are an answer related with your issue that say: "The Target closed exception is thrown when you are trying to run a function, but the target (tab) was already closed." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51629151/puppeteer-protocol-error-page-navigate-target-closed

Comment: @ManuelMB I tried to run this program on remote desktop and it worked perfect. I guess the problem is in my PC especially in my chrome browser.

Comment: I am glad you solve the issue. 