# I want to be able to click all connect buttons, after clicking the connect button a Dismiss button appears so I want to be able to click it as well

Tags: javascript, for-loop, puppeteer

The for loop isnt working, i dont know why

```js
const connectButtons = await page.$$('.artdeco-button.artdeco-button--2.artdeco-button--secondary.ember-view:not(.artdeco-button--circle):not(.artdeco-button--muted):not([aria-label="Message "]')
    
    for (let i = 0; i < connectButtons.length; i++) {
        try {
            await connectButtons[i].click();
            console.log(`Clicked button ${i + 1}`);
            page.click('button[aria-label="Dismiss"')
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Error clicking button ${i + 1}: ${error.message}`);
        }
    }
```

I expected all connect buttons to be clicked and let me connect with everyone

Comment: You didn't `await page.click('button[aria-label="Dismiss"')`. Did your code give an error message, like [target closed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68231165/6243352)?

Comment: using that doesnt work, `DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55919/devtools/browser/ce7933be-22f1-4d48-b7c0-f1854b662e1e
[21700:3640:1020/161759.800:ERROR:socket_manager.cc(141)] Failed to resolve address for stun.l.google.com., errorcode: -105
Error clicking button 1: Node is detached from document
Error clicking button 2: Node is detached from document
Error clicking button 3: Node is detached from document
Error clicking button 4: Node is detached from document
, etc. is the error

Comment: Thanks for the error message. Can you [edit] that into your post? Well, then there must be some other problem. All Puppeteer promises need to be awaited--it's basically non-negotiable, or you get "target closed" and "node is detached" errors like this. Please provide a [mcve], since beyond that missing `await`, there's nothing obviously wrong with the snippet on its own.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you always have elements not detached also after interacting with the page, you may fetch all of them once at beginning just for the sake of knowing how many there are, and then refetch each one of them at each iteration.

Plus, after clicking the connect button, you may wait for the Dismiss button to exist before trying to click it using `waitForSelector`.

Try this:

```
const connectButtonsSelector = '.artdeco-button.artdeco-button--2.artdeco-button--secondary.ember-view:not(.artdeco-button--circle):not(.artdeco-button--muted):not([aria-label="Message "]';

let buttonsCount = await page.$$(connectButtonsSelector).length;

for (let i = 0; i < buttonsCount; i++) {
    try {
        // Re-fetch the list of buttons on each iteration
        const connectButton = await page.$$(connectButtonsSelector)[i];
        if (!connectButton) {
            console.log('No more buttons to click.');
            break;
        }

        await connectButton.click();
        console.log(`Clicked button ${i + 1}`);

        // Wait for the "Dismiss" button to appear
        await page.waitForSelector('button[aria-label="Dismiss"]', { timeout: 5000 });

        await page.click('button[aria-label="Dismiss"');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error clicking button ${i + 1}: ${error.message}`);
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont know why, but this code doesn't click the buttons at all. Like even the console is empty for some reason. I appreciate the idea though.

Comment: I checked again what could be wrong but I couldn't understand. This code is using the same selector you use to fetch the `connect` buttons. The only difference is the fact I'm going to refetch all the buttons at each iteration because there's the chance that interacting with the page made the dom change somehow. I then only added a further condition waiting for the dismiss button to show up. Anyway it's impossible to verify because you didn't share the target

Comment: anyway that even the first click fails on the first connect button is very hard to diagnose blindly. Because that event would happen at the same exact conditions of your example. If you can't see it I may suspect the target has elements matching first with that selector that don't show up