# Why am I getting the error Error: kill ESRCH?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize-typescript

i I build a program with nodejs sequelize and typescript when I exit the process using ctrl+c it gives me the error:
node:internal/process/per_thread:233
throw errnoException(err, 'kill');
^

Error: kill ESRCH

how can i fix it?

Comment: TDLR; "ESRCH is thrown by kill when no such pid is running. Add a try-catch statement to log the error and get the line number. Then you'll need to dig into the command producing this error (or update your question)"

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47266005/unhandled-promise-rejection-rejection-id-1-error-kill-esrch

Comment: where do i nedd to put try ctach statment?